# I need a DISTINCT list of records based on one field and a date

Tags: sql, distinct

I am trying to formulate an SQL statement that will return a list of records that are distinct on one field, but if a duplicate record (based on the one field) is present with a newer date in the date field, then it should be selected as the "distinct" record.

ie.

```
Field 1  Field 2  Field 3
A        3/28/11  Jimmy
A        4/11/11  Tom
B        3/29/11  Harry
C        4/12/11  Tom
C        3/30/11  Jimmy
```

Would produce:

```
A        4/11/11  Tom
B        3/29/11  Harry
C        4/12/11  Tom
```

The "Distinct" field is Field 1.

Comment: What if two of them have the same date?  Where is your primary key?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.Field1, A.Field2, A.Field3
FROM myTable A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B.Field1, MAX(B.Field2) AS MaxDate
    FROM myTable B
    GROUP BY B.Field1) AS B
        ON A.Field1 = B.Field1 AND A.Field2 = B.MaxDate
ORDER BY A.Field1
```

Note: I haven't tried this query & am writing it of what it should be.

Comment: I suspect this is closer to my need, but the actual database (Access2007) is using two tables and looks closer to: